# Devise mail template for reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to add attachment to email sent on reseting password by devise (logo image) and also I want to use user's locale to localize email text.
Can anybody help and tell me what to override to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the logo image as an attachment.

To do so, follow the instructions in the link to override the default Devise::Mailer:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

Then, add the attachment using `attachments.inline['logo.png']=`:

```
def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
  attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read('app/assets/images/logo.png')
  super(record, opts)
end
```

And in the view you can use `attachments['logo.png'].url`:

```
<%= image_tag(attachments['logo.png'].url, alt: 'Logo') %>
```

Answer (score 3):

just run `rails generate devise:views` and edit template in `app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb`

Comment: But I can't add image in such a way. I recieve only bad link, when I'm trying to do it. I have to add an attachment to the message - how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using devise 4.3 for rails 5 app. Additional argument is required.

```
 def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png")
    super(record, token, opts)
 end
```